# Black Magic using Initializer_list and pack expansion

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, pack-expansion

To expand flexible function parameters, there is a method using `std::initializer_list`. However I couldn't understand it. Can anyone explain this in an understandable way?

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto print(T value, Args... args) {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
    return std::initializer_list<T>{([&] {
        std::cout << args << std::endl;
    }(), value)...};
}
```

Comment: There are three things happening here: [Lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), [parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack), and [the built-in comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator). Please study all three to understand what's happening.

Comment: A simpler C++11/C++14 way: `template <typename ... Args> void print (Args ... args) { using unused = int[]; (void)unused { 0, (std::cout << args << std::endl, 0)... }; }`

Comment: The C++17 way: `template <typename ... Args> void print (Args ... args) { ((std::cout << args << std::endl), ...); }`

Answer (score 7):

This is a very confused way of doing things, but C++14 requires that we do something similar. I'll explain the limitations and why it gets done this way (though there are clearer ways to do it).

The goal of this code is to repeatedly print out each parameter it is given on a separate line. Since the function is a variadic template, it needs to use a pack expansion on the expression `std::cout << args << std::endl`.

Your first thought might be `(std::cout << args << std::endl) ...;`. However, that's not actually a valid thing you can do in C++14. In fact, you can only perform a pack expansion in the context of a comma-delimited sequence of values in C++14, such as a list of arguments to a function or whatever. You can't just expand a pack as a naked statement.

Well, one place that you *can* expand a pack into is a braced-init-list (the `{}` for initializing objects). However, `{(std::cout << args << std::endl) ...};` doesn't work either. There's nothing wrong with the expansion; the problem is the braced-init-list itself. Grammatically, a braced-init-list can only appear when you are *initializing* an object. And a naked `{}` as a statement doesn't initialize anything. So you can't use it there.

So you have to use the `{}` to initialize something. The typical idiom for this is to initialize an empty array. For example:

```
int unused[] = {0, ((std::cout << args << std::endl), 0)...};
```

The initial `0,` is needed in case `args` is empty; you can't initialize an unsized array with no elements. The trailing `, 0` in the expansion expression is part of a comma expression.

In C++, the expression `(1, 2)` means "evaluate the expression 1, then discard its value, evaluate the expression 2, and use that as the result of the total expression." So using that in the pack expansion means `output one argument, discard the result, and use 0 as the result of the expression. So each pack expansion is just a really fancy way of saying "0", as far as the result of the expression is concerned.

In the end, `unused` just stores a bunch of zeros. We use a side-effect of the initialization of `unused` as a way to force C++ to unpack a pack expansion.

In the code you show, the user decided to use the braced-init-list to directly initialize an `initializer_list<T>`. That's valid as well, and it has the minor benefit of working on an empty `args`. The problem is that the user then returns this object. This is bad because nobody can actually use that return value.

`initializer_list`s don't own the objects they reference. A temporary array is created at the cite of the braced-init-list which holds those objects; the `initializer_list` just points into that array. The temporary array will be destroyed at the end of the `return` statement, so the caller will get an `initializer_list` that points into a bunch of *destroyed* objects. Also, it invokes the copy constructor of `T` a bunch of times needlessly, since nobody can use the return value.

So this is a confused and bad example of a common idiom. It would be better to remove the `return` and just make it a `void` function.

C++17 just lets us do this directly without having to initialize an array:

```
((std::cout << args << std::endl), ...);
```

This is a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) over the comma operator. It will invoke each sub-expression first to last on the values in `args`.

Comment: Thanks! So the way I've provided is not safe since the `initializer_list` points a temporary array of `value`s which would be destroyed right after the `print` function returns. One more question: does the expression `(std::cout << args << std::endl) ...;` mean  `cout` all args recursively?

Comment: @YueyangPan: That expression means nothing, since it doesn't compile in C++ of any version. If you're talking about the C++17 version, note the presence of both an additional set of parens and a comma; both of these are very important.

Comment: Why do I need the additional parenthesis in C++17? Is this simply a new syntax?  Still little confused with the parens.

Comment: @YueyangPan: It's a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold). Since your question was about C++14, I didn't feel the need to go into any greater detail than that. It's an operator-based way of unpacking packs, but it has to be done within the context of an operator expression. So you need parentheses to establish the boundaries of the expression being folded over.

Comment: Now I understood. Thanks again.